# how can update dropdown values without refreshing all the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

On form dropdown list i want to load a list with an updated list of a mysql table. I'am sending the form variables across to a php and posting them into a mysql table. the same page displays the full table data. I want to refresh the dropdown list only without refreshing  all the page. 
The idea is to get list values adding via another page
    
    
    
    
    Learning Ajax

```
<script>
function dynamic_Select(dropdown) {


 $('update').click( function(event) {
                         event.preventDefault();
                            $("#result").load($(this).attr('#input'));
                        });
                        }
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#999999">
<div style="margin-left: 500px;">
<form name="ajaxlearning" id="ajaxlearning">
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown"> 
       <option value="">Select supplier</option>
<?php
include('config.php');



?>
    <?php

    $sqlsupplier=mysql_query("SELECT id ,name FROM item");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlsupplier))

    {
        echo "<option value = '{$row['id']}'";

        echo ">{$row['name']}</option>";}

       ?>

    </select>


<input type='button' onclick='dynamic_Select(dropdown)' name='update' value='Status Update'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think it's what i'm doing already NO?but when i refreash the list via button nothing is changed

Comment: And please, don't rely on the idiocy that some browsers provide named fields as global Javascript variables. Always use `getElement(s)By` or jQuery selectors to get an element by its id, class or tag name

Comment: `$('update')` will select `<update>` HTML elements ... and there are no such elements (of course). You want to select the input with type button `$('input[type=button]').click(...)`

Comment: On top of all that, you want to .load() contents into the element with `id="result"` ... but there is no such element in your HTML document

Comment: wooow ... even more ... you try to get the value of the attribute `#input` of the button. What is it you WANT to get here?

Comment: i'm losed it's the first time that i using ajax can you explain more please

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged jQuery: You could retrieve the new list with

```
$.get('path/to/listgenerator.php', function(data) {
    $('#idOfYourSelect').html(data);
});
```

listgenerator.php would look up the list items in your database and return the -tags.

Comment: sorry but i dont undrestand

Comment: This needs to be placed in your event handler: $('update').click( function(event) { *here* }). listgenerator.php would be your config.php I guess and #idOfYourSelect is #dropdown.

Comment: but i do the execution of the query in the same page main.php